# Swift JSONDecode decoding arrays/dictionary fails

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

This was the struct I was using

```
struct earthquakeResults: Codable{
    let datetime: String
    let depth: String
    //let eqid: Any
    let lat: String
    let lng: String
    let magnitude: String
    //let src: Any
}
```

This is when I was trying to get the JSON result, and I used a geocoder to get long/lat which I then used to get the north/south/east/west for the api call

```
let urlAsString = "http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=\(north)&south=\(south)&east=\(east)&west=\(west)&username=antoniogomez"

let url = URL(string: urlAsString)!
        let urlSession = URLSession.shared


        let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            var err: NSError?

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            let jsonResult = try! decoder.decode([earthquakeResults].self, from: data!)

            if (err != nil) {
                print("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }

            print(jsonResult)

            let dt = jsonResult[0].datetime
            let dp = jsonResult[0].depth
            let lt = jsonResult[0].lat
            let lg = jsonResult[0].lng
            let mag = jsonResult[0].magnitude

            let res = "Results : \(dt) \(dp) \(lt) \(lg) \(mag)"
            print(res)
})

        jsonQuery.resume()
```

I was getting the error:

> Thread 3: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
>   "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.",
>   underlyingError: nil))

this is what the JSON looked like:

```
{
    earthquakes =     (
                {
            datetime = "2012-10-09 10:32:04";
            depth = "10.2";
            eqid = c000d4li;
            lat = "-61.0333";
            lng = "153.9596";
            magnitude = "6.4";
            src = us;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2013-01-15 15:09:36";
            depth = 10;
            eqid = b000epcu;
            lat = "-62.5663";
            lng = "-161.3457";
            magnitude = "6.1";
            src = us;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2019-07-23 10:33:10";
            depth = 10;
            eqid = us70004r4f;
            lat = "-61.2936";
            lng = "154.063";
            magnitude = 6;
            src = us;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2016-01-31 17:43:40";
            depth = 10;
            eqid = us20004w6c;
            lat = "-63.2868";
            lng = "169.1522";
            magnitude = 6;
            src = us;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2016-02-23 18:10:40";
            depth = "7.71";
            eqid = us10004s4c;
            lat = "-63.1275";
            lng = "144.7936";
            magnitude = "5.9";
            src = us;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2017-06-03 19:32:50";
            depth = 10;
            eqid = us20009kit;
            lat = "-62.5792";
            lng = "155.834";
            magnitude = "5.9";
            src = us;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2010-12-24 04:48:54";
            depth = "10.7";
            eqid = c0000ueu;
            lat = "-63.5903";
            lng = "-167.4271";
            magnitude = "5.9";
            src = us;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2007-11-04 19:35:36";
            depth = "7.5";
            eqid = 2007jhax;
            lat = "-67.1317";
            lng = "111.5551";
            magnitude = "5.8";
            src = us;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2007-08-02 22:41:16";
            depth = "11.7";
            eqid = 2007fpab;
            lat = "-62.8736";
            lng = "145.4634";
            magnitude = "5.7";
            src = us;
        },
                {
            datetime = "2006-03-23 12:57:41";
            depth = 10;
            eqid = kqbp;
            lat = "-62.5198";
            lng = "164.8179";
            magnitude = "5.7";
            src = us;
        }
    );
}
```

And this is what I was originally doing, but I couldn't figure out how to get the datetime, and magnitude (or any of the other details) so I figured I would try and use the decoder instead:

```
var jsonResult = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
if (err != nil) {
    print("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: The error message says it all.

Answer (score 1):

From the response you are getting a json(not an array of json) that contains the expected list of json objects. So your response will be decoded as an object that has that list. Create data types as below.

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let earthquakes: [Earthquake]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case earthquakes = "earthquakes"
    }
}

// MARK: - Earthquake
struct Earthquake: Codable {
    let datetime: String
    let depth: String
    let lat: String
    let lng: String
    let magnitude: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case datetime = "datetime"
        case depth = "depth"
        case lat = "lat"
        case lng = "lng"
        case magnitude = "magnitude"
    }
}
```

And parse result as,

```
let urlAsString = "http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=\(north)&south=\(south)&east=\(east)&west=\(west)&username=antoniogomez"

let url = URL(string: urlAsString)!
        let urlSession = URLSession.shared


        let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            var err: NSError?

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            let jsonResult = try! decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data!)

            if (err != nil) {
                print("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }

            print(jsonResult.earthquakes)

            let dt = jsonResult.earthquakes[0].datetime
            let dp = jsonResult.earthquakes[0].depth
            let lt = jsonResult.earthquakes[0].lat
            let lg = jsonResult.earthquakes[0].lng
            let mag = jsonResult.earthquakes[0].magnitude

            let res = "Results : \(dt) \(dp) \(lt) \(lg) \(mag)"
            print(res)
})

        jsonQuery.resume()
```

Comment: Why explicit CodingKeys? You don’t need them if the keys match the struct members.

Comment: @vadian You are right, they can be removed. Actually i used this [web app](app.quicktype.io) to create types and pasted as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by Kamran is good.

However you need to change the "App Transport Security Settings" in the plist file to allow the link for to get the data... like so:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>api.geonames.org</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

add the above snippet in the plist file under the first couple of lines:

```
</plist>
</dict>
```

And then finally you need to change the data type for your struct. You are trying to fetch String's when the JSON is returning Double's. So change the struct from the answer above to this:

```
    struct Earthquake: Codable {
    let datetime: String
    let depth: Double
    let lat: Double
    let lng: Double
    let magnitude: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case datetime = "datetime"
        case depth = "depth"
        case lat = "lat"
        case lng = "lng"
        case magnitude = "magnitude"
    }
}
```